# Eclipse-Javascript - Strange behaviour with prototype functions?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, prototype

I'm using Eclipse IDE for JavaScript Web Developers, OS is Linux Ubuntu.

I create a class, then add a function to the prototype.

If in that function I access a property and assign a value to it, Eclipse considers that function as a class in the outline. Function f is seen as a method of A but also as a new class.

[image: function f seen as a class]

This happens when in that function I assign

```
this.B = 'ccc';
```

If I put in the constructor a setter of B (set_B()) and call this setter from the function f instead of directly assign a new value to B, Eclipse doesn't see f as a class.

[image: function f not seen as a class]

Everything is ok also if I assign a value in this way:

```
this.B += 1
```

But since a assign a value with the '=' instead of '+=' then the function is seen as a class.

Is that normal or is that a bug?

Comment: Don't forget that there aren't real classes in javascript. You have only Objects (Instances), and can extend their Prototypes. So is your problem anything related to the functionality, or is it only the visual representation in eclipse?

Comment: My problem is about splitting into modules my 'classes'. From a module I don't see correctly the properties of the classes in the other modules since I assing to those properties a value outside the constructor. I mean, Eclipse don't see them.

Comment: I find Eclipse a great IDE and I think this is a weird behaviour, since I can't take advantage of the massive help Eclipse gives to the developers. I can't understand.

Comment: Part of the problem is that JavaScript is so dynamic at runtime that even the best IDEs struggle with any sort of autocompletion or outlining.  Remember that at runtime nothing about a JavaScript object is static, and that virtually everything can be modified, including inside eval statements.  In contrast, a statically typed compiled language has well defined method names that can't change at runtime.

Comment: In addition, the whole concept of "Class" which eclipse outlines here, is somewhat misleading. Consider also code like var obj = {}; obj.f = function()... return obj; This is also a completely valid Javascript-Object, without using any prototype logic.

Comment: Right, but it makes no sense, in my opinion, that I can't assign to a property and Eclipse makes all this mess.